# How can I join 2 csv in python without using panda.?

Tags: python, csv, join

one csv file has foll columns

count, duration, items, id

```
1,na,na,123
2,na,na,456
3,na,na,789
```

Other csv file contains

xyz_id, xyz_images

```
123,1
123,2
123,3
123,4
123,56
123,7
123,8
456,9
456,12
456,23
```

Condition is I cant use pandas, then how to join these 2 csv files ?

Desired output is

xyz_id, xyz_images,count, duration, items, id

```
123,1,1,na,na,123
123,2,1,na,na,123
123,3,1,na,na,123
123,4,1,na,na,123
123,56,1,na,na,123
123,7,1,na,na,123
123,8,1,na,na,123
456,9,2,na,na,456
456,12,2,na,na,456
456,23,2,na,na,456
```

Motive was to join ids of both csv together to combine in 1 file.

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/FW__Json_FIles/withoutpanda.csv') as f,open('/home/user/Downloads/FW__Json_FIles/forms.csv') as csvfile1:
reader1 = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
reader2=csv.reader(csvfile1,delimiter='|')
try:
    for row1 in reader1:
        print(row1[0])
    for row2 in reader2:
        print (row2[3])
except csv.Error as e:
    sys.exit('file {}, line {}: {}'.format(filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

After this i was not able to check how to join these 2 files  based upon these 2 keys as row1[0] and row2[3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of lists for the two CSVs, and manually do the join with a for loop:

```
records1=[]
with open('csvfile1', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        records1.append(line.split(','))

records2=[]
with open('csvfile2', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        records2.append(line.split(','))


for (count, duration, items, id_) in records1:
    for (xyz_id, xyz_images) in records2:
        if id_ == xyz_id:
            print(xyz_id, xyz_images, count, duration, items, id_, sep=',')
```

prints:

```
123,1,1,na,na,123
123,2,1,na,na,123
123,3,1,na,na,123
123,4,1,na,na,123
123,56,1,na,na,123
123,7,1,na,na,123
123,8,1,na,na,123
456,9,2,na,na,456
456,12,2,na,na,456
456,23,2,na,na,456
```

if number of lines is high, and performance becomes an issue, consider indexing the data into a dictionary of lists, and replace the inner for loop with a dictionary lookup.

---

If you have to output all these columns into the csv file, then do the following:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as of:
    writer=csv.writer(of,delimiter='|')
    for (count, duration, items, id_) in records1:
        for (xyz_id, xyz_images) in records2:
            if id_ == xyz_id:
                writer.writerow([xyz_id, xyz_images, count, duration, items, id_])
```

Comment: If i have to output all these columns into csv file with '|' pipe delimeter then what to do and that sep is also not working.. it is showing syntax error

Comment: if you are using Python 2, add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this here for reference in case anyone needs it. Nice solution using the native csv module:

```
### test1.csv
col1,col2,col3
1,    2,    3
4,    5,    6

### test2.csv
col1, col3, col4
7,    8,    9,    
10,   11,   12,   


### new_csv.csv
col1, col2, col3, col4
1     2     3
4     5     6
7           8     9 
10          11    12

import csv

headers = []
data = []
for csv_file in ['test1.csv', 'test2.csv']:
    with open(f'{csv_file}', 'r') as f:
        temp_csv = csv.DictReader(f)
        headers += td.fieldnames
        for row in td:
            data.append(row)

headers = sorted(set(headers))
with open('new_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```